# Xamarin android BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationCallback OnAuthenticationError not available

Tags: xamarin.android, biometrics, android-9.0-pie

There is no override method for 'OnAuthenticationError' callback in Xamarin android version of BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationCallback class. How can I handle any error callbacks in that case?

Native android has following override methods

- **void onAuthenticationError(int errorCode, CharSequence errString)**
- void onAuthenticationFailed()
- void onAuthenticationHelp(int helpCode, CharSequence helpString)
- void
  onAuthenticationSucceeded(BiometricAuthenticator.AuthenticationResult
  result)
- void onAuthenticationSucceeded(BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationResult
  result)

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/biometrics/BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationCallback.html

while xamarin android only has the following

- void OnAuthenticationHelp ([GeneratedEnum] BiometricAcquiredStatus
  helpCode, string helpString)
- void OnAuthenticationHelp
  ([GeneratedEnum] BiometricAcquiredStatus helpCode, ICharSequence helpString)
- OnAuthenticationHelp ([GeneratedEnum] BiometricAcquiredStatus helpCode, string helpString)
- void OnAuthenticationFailed ();

Answer (score 0):

It is claimed that this binding issue is fixed in Xamarin.Android 9.2. You may want to update your Xamarin.Android version and see if it works.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/release-notes/9/9.2

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/399276/missing-method-bindings-in-androidhardwarebiometri.html

https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/pull/2545